# How do I re-enable the IPMI temperature sensors?

Tags: linux, hardware, ipmi, physical-environment, ipmitool

I've never had a problem reading temperature sensors with ipmitool on my server, but recently the temperature readings started showing up as disabled:

```
# ipmitool sdr list
Temp             | disabled          | ns
Temp             | disabled          | ns
Ambient Temp     | 21 degrees C      | ok
CMOS Battery     | 0x00              | ok
VCORE            | 0x00              | ok
VDDIO            | 0x00              | ok
VDDA             | 0x00              | ok
VTT              | 0x00              | ok
VCORE            | 0x00              | ok
VDDIO            | 0x00              | ok
VDDA             | 0x00              | ok
VTT              | 0x00              | ok
VDD 1.2V PG      | 0x00              | ok
Linear PG        | 0x00              | ok
```

I am using OpenIPMI 2.0.19 and ipmitool 1.8.12. How can I re-enable my temperature sensors?

Answer (score 1):

I recently had an issue like that on a Supermicro board after upgrading the IPMI firmware. The solution was to reset the IPMI system to factory defaults.

Comment: I haven't touched the firmware though. It seemingly stopped working after a software update.

Answer (score 0):

Usually for this kind of problem I do a ''mc reset cold''

Comment: That just made the fans incredibly loud and did not fix the issue.

Comment: That seems like the BMC is hung and the fan control hardware is going to maximum cooling as a fail-safe measure. You may need to completely remove (unplug) power from the system to fully reset the BMC, and then check the manufacturer's support website for a firmware update that would prevent the problem from re-occurring.